# Different instructions for one button

Tags: java, android

I want to do different things for one button.
But I am changing instructions after the button was clicked every time.
First I am creating two buttons, after I clicked the button I want it to change its text. For each text I want to create different instruction.
I created an `if`/`else` for this. But I am not sure why my isn’t not working.
I only do instructions in the first statement.

Here is my code.

```
package com.example.iqbal.destini;

public class MAINPAGE extends AppCompatActivity {

Button mAnswer_1_Button;
Button mAnswer_2_Button;
TextView mTextbody;
int counter1 = 0;
int counter2 = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainpage);

    mAnswer_1_Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer_1);
    mAnswer_2_Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer_2);
    mTextbody = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_body);

    if(mTextbody.getText().toString().equals(getResources().getString(R.string.T1_Story)) && mAnswer_2_Button.getText().toString().equals(getResources().getString(R.string.T1_Ans2))&&mAnswer_1_Button.getText().toString().equals(getResources().getString(R.string.T1_Ans1)) ){
        mAnswer_1_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mTextbody.setText(R.string.T3_Story);
                mAnswer_1_Button.setText(R.string.T3_Ans1);
                mAnswer_2_Button.setText(R.string.T3_Ans2);
            }
        });

        mAnswer_2_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mTextbody.setText(R.string.T2_Story);
                mAnswer_1_Button.setText(R.string.T2_Ans1);
                mAnswer_2_Button.setText(R.string.T2_Ans2);

            }
        });
    }
    else if(mTextbody.getText().toString().equals(getResources().getString(R.string.T2_Story))&& mAnswer_2_Button.getText().toString().equals(getResources().getString(R.string.T2_Ans2))&&mAnswer_1_Button.getText().toString().equals(getResources().getString(R.string.T2_Ans1))){

        mAnswer_1_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mTextbody.setText(R.string.T3_Story);
                mAnswer_1_Button.setText(R.string.T3_Ans1);
                mAnswer_2_Button.setText(R.string.T3_Ans2);
            }
        });
        mAnswer_2_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mTextbody.setText(R.string.T4_End);
                mAnswer_1_Button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mAnswer_2_Button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }
    else   if(mTextbody.getText().toString().equals(getResources().getString(R.string.T3_Story))&& mAnswer_2_Button.getText().toString().equals(getResources().getString(R.string.T3_Ans2))&&mAnswer_1_Button.getText().toString().equals(getResources().getString(R.string.T3_Ans1))){
        mAnswer_1_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mTextbody.setText(R.string.T6_End);
                mAnswer_1_Button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mAnswer_2_Button.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        });
        **mAnswer_2_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mTextbody.setText(R.string.T5_End);
                mAnswer_1_Button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mAnswer_2_Button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }
}
}**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mTextbody.getText()` always is empty where it's currently located (unless you have a default string in the TextView)

Move the if conditions into the onClick method body.

Conditionally  perform the action. Don't conditionally add the listener.

And you only need one OnClickListener per button